# Add Value to First JSON PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have some php to show result as JSON like this

```
$dp = $_GET['dp'];

$query = mysql_query("select trip_id, trip_desc from current_data where dispatcher='".$dp."'");

$json = array();    

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

    $tripdata["code"]=$row["trip_id"]." - ".$row["trip_code"];

    $json[] = $tripdata;

}

echo json_encode($json);
```

and result like this

```
[{"code":"S1.001 - UK"},{"code":"S1.002 - US"},{"code":"S1.003 - CA"}]
```

How to add value in First Result of my JSON,
i want to result like this?

```
 [**{"code":"Select Country"}**,{"code":"S1.001 - UK"},{"code":"S1.002 - US"},{"code":"S1.003 - CA"}]
```

Thanks

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Push the first value to the array before the while loop.

Comment: I know this method will risk with SQL Inject, but this Script only backend for Andorid APK.
thanks for your response guys,,, ^_^

Comment: What does that ^ mean? Are you saying it is OK to ignore the risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the first value to the array before the while loop:

```
$json[] = [
       'code' => 'Select Country',
     ];

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

    $tripdata["code"]=$row["trip_id"]." - ".$row["trip_code"];

    $json[] = $tripdata;

}

echo json_encode($json);
```

This will add a the desired value in the beginning of json.

## Note:

`mysql_*` is deprecated as of [php-5.5](/questions/tagged/php-5.5) and removed as of [php-7](/questions/tagged/php-7). So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: Thanks mega6382 for your Answer

Comment: @coco_nk4l If the answer was helpful, please be sure to accept it.